# Why ImageView is working with a video file path?

Tags: android, video, android-recyclerview, android-imageview

I have a `RecyclerView` with a list of video files. Accidentally, I have used an `ImageView` for the list item layout (instead of `VideoView` or `ExoPlayer`'s `PlayerView`) with a file path to a video as URL passed to it.

But it is still working. It seems that the `ImageView` shows the first frame (or one of the frames at the beginning of the video).

My question would be: Why is that so ? I know that the `ImageView` is not able to play those video files but why it is showing a frame ?

Here some relevant pieces from my project:

```
// fragment responsible for displaying the list of videos using RecyclerView
class GalleryVideoFilesFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentGalleryVideoFilesBinding
    private lateinit var mediaList: MutableList<File>

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        binding = FragmentGalleryVideoFilesBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val adapter = GalleryVideoFilesAdapter()

        binding.galleryVideoFiles.adapter = adapter

        // Walk through all files in the root directory
        // We reverse the order of the list to present the last photos first
        mediaList = DirectoryPath.getOutputDirectory(requireContext()).listFiles { file ->
            VIDEO_EXTENSION_WHITELIST.contains(file.extension.toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT))
        }?.sortedDescending()?.toMutableList() ?: mutableListOf()

        adapter.submitList(mediaList)

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return binding.root
    }

}
```

Here the adapter class:

```
class GalleryVideoFilesAdapter : ListAdapter<File, GalleryVideoFilesAdapter.ViewHolder>(
    GalleryVideoFilesDiffCallback()
) {

    class ViewHolder(private val binding: GalleryVideoFilesItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(file: File){
            with(binding){
                viewModel = GalleryVideoFilesFragmentViewModel(file)
                executePendingBindings()
            }
        }
    }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), R.layout.gallery_video_files_item, parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(getItem(position))
    }
}

private class GalleryVideoFilesDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<File>() {

    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: File, newItem: File): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: File, newItem: File): Boolean {
        return oldItem.absolutePath == newItem.absolutePath
    }
}
```

Here the XML layout file for the video item which uses an `ImageView` (instead of `VideoView` or `PlayerView`)

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.celik.abdullah.mylim6.gallery.fragments.allMedia.videos.GalleryVideoFilesFragmentViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/gallery_video_item"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:videoFromUrl="@{viewModel.videoFilePath}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Since I am using Data Binding, here the BindingAdapter.kt content:

```
@BindingAdapter("videoFromUrl")
fun bindVideoFromUrl(view: ImageView, imageUrl: String?) {
    if (!imageUrl.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        Glide.with(view.context)
            .load(imageUrl)
            .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
            .into(view)
    }
}
```

Comment: Glide supports showing a video thumbnail in an ImageView.

Comment: Is that happening automatically ? because I did not instruct Glide to do that

Comment: Yes. Glide handles it automatically.